# CMYK Droplet (batch convert)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I would like to know if someone can share a clear step by step process to creating and saving a RBG to CMYK batch process, then create a droplet for it, have the droplet on my desktop so I can simply drag an image/images over the droplet which will automatically start the process through Photoshop.

I used to have this tool set at my previous job but never learnt how to do it. I have googled it many a times however, it seems to not do anything once dragging an image over. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### Create your action

1. Open Photoshop and create a new document in CMYK colour mode (any size).
2. Open the **Actions** panel.
3. Click the `Create new action` button. Give your action a name ('CMYK > RGB') and click `Record`.
4. Now, with your action recording, change the image's colour mode (`Image > Mode > CMYK Color`).
5. On the Actions panel, click the `Stop playing/recording` button.

Your action is now saved in the Actions panel.

### Create your Droplet

6. Click `File > Automate > Create Droplet`.
7. Set up your Droplet:

   - Under `Save Droplet In` select a folder to create the Droplet in and give it a name. You may want to create a 'Droplets' folder on your desktop.
   - Under `Play` select the set you created your action in, and your action.
   - And under `Destination` select `Folder`. For this,  you may want to make an 'Exports' folder inside your Droplets folder.
   - Click `Choose` and select the folder where you'd like the new RGB version of your image to be saved.
   - You can specify extra options here, such as file naming conventions and the link, but I'll just stick to the basics.
8. Click `Ok`.

A Droplet is now saved in the folder you specified.

### Using the Droplet

To use the Droplet, simply drag your CMYK image onto the Droplet icon in your Droplets folder, and an RGB version if the image will be created in the Exports folder.

If you want your action to export an image at a specific resolution, size or quality, you can record these steps as part of your action.

Comment: Thanks so much, this works! However, when I select files and drag them over the droplet, it converts them but then I have to individually save each one. Once it is saved, the new file is directed to a different folder (not the original). Previously I was able to drag the images over the dropbox, they would automatically open and go through the conversion process, save themselves and remain in the original folder but now as CMYK files rather than RGB. Do you or does anyone know how to do this? Thanks,
M

Comment: But to answer your question, you could probably set the file to save in the same folder by adding a **Save As** step to your action and then using the *Override Action 'Save As' Commands* section in the **Create Droplet** dialog